# Draw a rounded rectangle

Tags: ios, swift

How is it possible to draw a rounded rectangle looks like this:

[image: needed rectangle]

Does someone know how to implement this?

Comment: post the json ...............

Comment: Where is your `JSON` file?

Comment: The JSON doesn't contain a `id` value. *"How can I solve this problem?"* You look at the error message, it's trying to tell what's wrong ... in a round-a-bout way

Comment: 1) don't use try!. Use do/try/catch. 2) The error you're getting says there's not a value for an `id`. Declare it `let id: Int?`

Answer (score 1):

Just follow all the steps .

**Step#1 - Create Model Like This**

```
class Teachers: Codable {
  var id: Int?
  var name: String?
  var position: String?
  var subj: Int?
  var depart: Int?
  var lect: Int?
  var pract: Int?
}
```

**Step 2 : Map like this**

```
  do {
        // Decode data to object
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "JSON_DATA_TEACHERS", withExtension: "json")
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        self.teachers = try JSONDecoder().decode([Teachers].self, from: jsonData)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }catch {
                print("Json Mapping Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
      }
```

Comment: Using a `Try?' in `Do..Catch` is irrelevant. You don't need optional assignment `?`

Comment: Then your json data will be different

Comment: **Never** print `error.localizedDescription` when catching `Codable` errors. You get a generic message rather than the real error. Print always just `error`.

Comment: yeah for actual error , you need to print error only